# 2 Different Json Objects are printed as a response, how to separate them and read the value of an element in the second Object

Tags: java, response, jsonpath

I am getting multiple json objects in a http response.

Eg:

```
{
    "result": {
        "Status": "complete",
        "id1": "<id1>",
        "id2": "<id2>",
        "Fields": [{
            "fid": "1",
            "FName": "<name>"
        }, {
            "fid": "2",
            "FName": "<name>"
        }, {
            "fid": "3",
            "FName": "<name>"
        }, {
            "fid": "4",
            "FName": "<name>"
        }]
    }
}
```

The next object is

```
{
    "result": {
        "Status": "complete",
        "id1": "<id1>",
        "id2": "<id2>",
        "Fields": [{
            "fid": "1",
            "FName": "<name>"
        }, {
            "fid": "2",
            "FName": "<name>"
        }, {
            "fid": "3",
            "FName": "<name>"
        }, {
            "fid": "4",
            "FName": "<name>"
        }],
        "TokenPairs": [{
            "Token1": "<token1>",
            "Token2": "<token2>",
            "FieldMatches": {
                "additionalProp1": {
                    "Score": 0,
                    "FalseDiscoveryRate": 0
                },
                "additionalProp2": {
                    "Score": 0,
                    "FalseDiscoveryRate": 0
                },
                "additionalProp3": {
                    "Score": 0,
                    "FalseDiscoveryRate": 0
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I actually want to check the `TokenPairs` but when I check the `jsonPath` it picks up the 1st object and returns null. How can I skip the 1st object and go to the second object? I m trying to solve it with adding the response (String) to JsonObject but am getting some errors.

Comment: Show your code and explain what kind of environment you're working in (console application, GUI application, Jersey, Spring MVC).

Comment: Is that an array of results? Can you please post the full response? Are you using Java?

Comment: @ReazMurshed this is the full response, which I have broken down into 2 different parts here, in my respose i just get it as a whole printed one after another. Yes am using java

Comment: If this is the full response, then this is not a valid JSON response. The response should have an opening third brace `[` and a closing `]` brace to indicate that this is an array of results.

Comment: @ReazMurshed it has 2 separate json objects, is there a way I can just ignore the 1st object and go into the second object? (Its not a json array)

Comment: I get the idea and found a solution for you which will separate the two JSON Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution for you. I would like to provide you the following function which will give you two separate JSON String.

```
public void JSONSeparator(String JsonString) {
   try {
        JSONObject object1 = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonString.replaceAll("\\s+", "")).nextValue();
        String firstJson = object1.toString().trim();
        String nextJson = jsonString.replaceAll("\\s+", "").substring(firstJson.length());

        System.out.println("First JSON String: " + firstJson);
        System.out.println("Second JSON String: " + nextJson);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The idea is to take the first JSON token, and then get the remaining part of the string after you get the first. I used the [`JSONTokener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html#nextValue) for picking up the first `JSONObject`. Then took the length of the object and hence I got the second JSON String using `substring` method.

The `JsonString` that I used to pass through this function was the following.

```
private String jsonString = "{\n" +
    "    \"result\": {\n" +
    "        \"Status\": \"complete\",\n" +
    "        \"id1\": \"<id1>\",\n" +
    "        \"id2\": \"<id2>\",\n" +
    "        \"Fields\": [{\n" +
    "            \"fid\": \"1\",\n" +
    "            \"FName\": \"<name>\"\n" +
    "        }, {\n" +
    "            \"fid\": \"2\",\n" +
    "            \"FName\": \"<name>\"\n" +
    "        }, {\n" +
    "            \"fid\": \"3\",\n" +
    "            \"FName\": \"<name>\"\n" +
    "        }, {\n" +
    "            \"fid\": \"4\",\n" +
    "            \"FName\": \"<name>\"\n" +
    "        }]\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "}" + "{" +
    "    \"result\": {\n" +
    "        \"Status\": \"complete\",\n" +
    "        \"id1\": \"<id1>\",\n" +
    "        \"id2\": \"<id2>\",\n" +
    "        \"Fields\": [{\n" +
    "            \"fid\": \"1\",\n" +
    "            \"FName\": \"<name>\"\n" +
    "        }, {\n" +
    "            \"fid\": \"2\",\n" +
    "            \"FName\": \"<name>\"\n" +
    "        }, {\n" +
    "            \"fid\": \"3\",\n" +
    "            \"FName\": \"<name>\"\n" +
    "        }, {\n" +
    "            \"fid\": \"4\",\n" +
    "            \"FName\": \"<name>\"\n" +
    "        }],\n" +
    "        \"TokenPairs\": [{\n" +
    "            \"Token1\": \"<token1>\",\n" +
    "            \"Token2\": \"<token2>\",\n" +
    "            \"FieldMatches\": {\n" +
    "                \"additionalProp1\": {\n" +
    "                    \"Score\": 0,\n" +
    "                    \"FalseDiscoveryRate\": 0\n" +
    "                },\n" +
    "                \"additionalProp2\": {\n" +
    "                    \"Score\": 0,\n" +
    "                    \"FalseDiscoveryRate\": 0\n" +
    "                },\n" +
    "                \"additionalProp3\": {\n" +
    "                    \"Score\": 0,\n" +
    "                    \"FalseDiscoveryRate\": 0\n" +
    "                }\n" +
    "            }\n" +
    "        }]\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "}";
```

Please note that, in order to get precise index for the `substring`, we need to remove all spaces and new lines using the `replaceAll` function that I had used. Hope that little trick helps you.